# JQzoom zoom window underneath next column image

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqzoom

When I use the JQZoom plugin I have a bunch of images on a 960.gs grid....

here's an example:
http://madlov.com/vintage-sunglasses

(Note: in the above link im using 'innerzoom', but if I were to use standard view, the zoomed window shows up behind the image next to it instead of on top)

I've inspected the ZoomWindow div and it has a

`z-index: 5001`

yet that doesn't seem to help.

**why do my zoomed images appear behind other images**

Comment: have a reference on `http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp`, learn more `position` and `z-index`.

Comment: Thanks for that  tip... its def. a stacking issue with z-index and position... Ill need to modify the JQzoom javascript somehow to make elements stack correctly, not sure how tho.

Comment: not sure whether this is you want or no `http://i42.tinypic.com/6nt7c2.jpg` when hover the image, the zoom image escape and out of all the divs, ahead the top of the screen. but they are too large, they will out of the screen width and height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely a stacking problem. Here's some more details on how the  stacking context works:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context

I've set up a fiddle as well at http://jsfiddle.net/aAMH2/1/ that may help.

Note the style tags at the bottom of the HTML - This style overrides the stacking problem specified in the CSS. If you're having trouble modifying the Javascript, or want a quick fix, this may do it (Just change the class name to .

Another option would be to run some jQuery after the page has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.zoomPad').css('z-index','auto');
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

In your application css file which seems to be getting cached or something, try setting the .zoompad z-index value to auto or getting rid of the z-index altogether. And if you're trying to get the zoomed images to appear over everything set the overflow property of .zoomWrapperImage to visible or getting rid of the overflow:hidden